Mac Pro 1,1 Linux Boot Issue
Booting a Linux distribution generates the following:

error: no sultable video mode found.
Booting in blind mode

Configuration:

Mac Pro 1,1 Late 2006
Apple ATI Radeon HD 5870
DVD drive works
6 GB RAM

Booting from USB Mint: Linux Mint 22 Xfce 64 bit
The GRUB script is the default:
setparams 'Start Linux Mint 22 Xfce 64-bit'

    set gfxpayload-keep
    linux        /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper username=mint hostname=mi\  
nt iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quit splash  
    initrd        /casper/initrd.lz    

I have seen suggestions to change splash to nosplash and add debug nomodeset
Also consulted Matt Gadient's excellent website.
I have tried various other distributions and versions: Ubuntu, Arch and most of those do not show an EFI from the Mac boot device selection.
Nothing seems to work although many people have reported success with this configuration.
Can anyone suggest a fix?

Try installing a BIOS booting Linux.

How much RAM is installed?

You're sure that the hardware actually works?

6 GB memory and machine boots fine with Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5. Just want to build a a Linux system on a second internal hard drive.

I'll try the Bios boot but that will take some doing.

Do you have a working internal DVD drive?

DVD Drives work

You may want to check to see if your Mac has the lasted firmware update. Apple started including firmware updates with OS X installations starting with about El Capitan 10.11. However, I believe Lion and older versions of OS X did not include any firmware updates. So, if necessary, you would need to do this manually. BTW, I needed to do a firmware update on a 2006 iMac before I could install a BIOS booting Windows.
About EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Mac computers
Your Mac has 64-bit processors, but a 32-bit EFI. A firmware update might give you a newer EFI version. Usually 64-bit Linux installers can only EFI boot from a flash drive if there is a 64-bit EFI. This is probably why you are having problems with Ubuntu and Arch. The Mint installer does have a 32-bit EFI boot file which maybe why this distribution appears in your Mac Startup Manager.
References
macPro1,1 - ubuntu 22.04 only sees ~2GB memory, memtest sees all 8GB

error: no sultable video mode found.
Booting in blind mode
Means video is not enabled or can't be enabled on boot although the above text comes to the display. So it is a matter of getting text to come to the display and not video. Modify the GRUB boot script adding:
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
One needs to initially be in console mode.
Specifically use the GRUB script:
setparams 'Start Linux Mint 22 Xfce 64-bit'

    GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
    set gfxpayload-keep
    linux        /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper username=mint hostname=mint iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quit splash
    initrd        /casper/initrd.lz

What happens is absolute magic. Text boot output is displayed and ends by going to a full Mint 22 Xfce desktop. Firefox works and I can now watch YouTube videos which was the objective all along.
